# How to make custom textview for text inside a circle in android?

Tags: android

I want to make a custom text view which should draw a circle around the text in white color.
Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: if you know answer,then answer me, otherwise don't waste your energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom TextView class, you'd just override onDraw() like so (very crude):

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Rect rect = canvas.getClipBounds();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(0xffffffff);
    canvas.drawCircle(rect.centerX(), rect.centerY(), radius, paint);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a subclass. You could also try to just style the textbox using a nine patch image.