# Draw text in circular view?

Tags: android

I want to draw a string say "stackoverflow" in circular view like below image can any one suggest how to do it. And also i need click event on each characer.

[image]

Comment: [Take a look at this, it's been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8343851/420015)

Comment: it was to draw a circle around text but not to draw text in circular way

Comment: [Okay, but it has been asked before. This link is right](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8337972/420015)

Comment: edited my post. how to click event

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make a customized view for this. in onDraw method, create a path object, add circle to that object, and then use Canvas Object to draw text on that path.

```
Path path = new Path();
path.addCircle(x, y, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
myCanvas.drawTextOnPath(myText, path, offset, 0, myPaint);
```

Edit:

use this line of code when using os 4.0 and above:

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Comment: but what about the click event on it

Comment: any idea about click event on it?

Comment: To have Click Event, you have to implement touch listener on the View, you need to set TouchListener on the View, and matches the character's co-ordinates with Touch Events Co-ordinates you can fire Click Event.

Comment: @AgarwalShankar how did you achieved this, could you please share the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at both `Path.addCircle` and `Canvas.drawTextOnPath` API.