# How to make TextView shape circle and set different background color based on condition

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView`, what I want is to make the `TextView` shape circle and then set different background colors based on different conditions I have used. I am able to set Background color based on different conditions but not able to make the `TextView` shape circle. So how that can be done. Please help me to solve this out.

**Code I have used:**

```
TextView txt_stage_display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_stage_display);

if(m_enStage[position] == enSTAGE_START)
{
    txt_stage_display.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D48393"));
}
else if(m_enStage[position] == enSTAGE_FLOW)
{
    txt_stage_display.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D48393"));
}
    else if(m_enStage[position] == enSTAGE_SAFE)
{
    txt_stage_display.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66B0CC"));
}
else if(m_enStage[position] == enSTAGE_UNSAFE)
{
    txt_stage_display.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D8C627"));
}
else if(m_enStage[position] == enSTAGE_FERTILE)
{
    txt_stage_display.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#67A05E"));
}
else
{
    txt_stage_display.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
}
```

Comment: Here is the solution for your question: [Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150642/draw-text-in-circular-view/10150970#10150970

Comment: I mean to say, i want textView look oval and at the same time want to set the background color of the textView based on condition which i alreday do in my code.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you have a relatively small amout of colors, you can create a drawable file for each color, for example create a file bg_red.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <shape>
      <solid android:color="#f00" />
      <corners
          android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
          android:topRightRadius="30dp"
          android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
          android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
          />
  </shape>
</item>
```

Then assign define the TextView:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="60dp" 
    android:text="X" 
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
    />
```

Note that the width is twice the radius of the background corner radius.

To change the color from code:

```
TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_blue);
```

Comment: actually I needed to remove item because was not valid and I changed to: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/neutral" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="60dp"
        android:topRightRadius="60dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="60dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="60dp" />
</shape>` PS! If you setted background to resource or color and then you want to set shape - it wont work. You mustn't set any background If you want use shape. Use color in shape xml file instead!

Comment: But how about my text is longer one character? It'll scale to oval :(

Comment: How would you change the code, so that it would be possible to change the color at runtime?

Comment: @androiddeveloper A simple way it so define a class that extends Drawable, in in the draw method call canvas.drawCircle. Then you can add a method like setColor

Comment: thanks for this ans yoah :) btw i have one question.how to fill white color inside this ??

Comment: you can add this one::  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#aaa"/>
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <stroke android:width="2dip"
                android:color="#eee"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

Comment: I think <item> tag is not required.

Answer (score 24):

To add up to the accepted answer, adding size tag inside shape and making sure height and width is large enough will make sure the background is circle even if textView has many characters!

> ```
> <shape>
>  <solid android:color="#f00" />
>  <corners
>     android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
>    android:topRightRadius="30dp"
>      android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
>      android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
>      />
>  <size 
>   android:height="25dp"
>    android:width="25dp"/>
> </shape>
> ```

Comment: `<size>` helped me.

Answer (score 6):

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);             
Drawable drawable = textView.getBackground();
drawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

works for me

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 1):

Add circular_hired.xml file into your drawable,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >


            <solid android:color="@color/map_hide_bg"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/map_hide_bg" />

    </shape>
```

but in you layout design xml file , you have to fix the width and height of textview. it will give the circular form.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMessages"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_message"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="@color/white_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt12"
            android:visibility="visible"
             />
```

i sure it will help you,

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by setting color to background drawable like this

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
((GradientDrawable)textView.getBackground()).setColor(R.color.my_color);
```