# How to Show Circular Text using TextView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to show text with circular shape in  my  android application.I know it is done with custome  textview but can some buddy give me proper code.I am also attaching image which type of look i want.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150642/draw-text-in-circular-view

Comment: sorry but its show complete text in a  cicle.

Comment: you need to understand it and change it according to  your need.

Answer (score 25):

you can try this tested and full working code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new GraphicsView(this));
    }

    static public class GraphicsView extends View {
        private static final String QUOTE = "This is a curved text";
        private Path circle;
        private Paint cPaint;
        private Paint tPaint;

        public GraphicsView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            int color = Color.argb(127, 255, 0, 255);

            circle = new Path();
            circle.addCircle(230, 350, 150, Direction.CW);

            cPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            cPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            cPaint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            cPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart);

            tPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            tPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            tPaint.setTextSize(50);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawTextOnPath(QUOTE, circle, 485, 20, tPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

the output will be:

[image]

Hope this help.

Answer (score 6):

Create a custom view and override the onDraw.  In the onDraw, create a path and use drawTextOnPath.  Something like this.  textToDraw is the text you want to display.  Paint is whatever paint you want.

```
@Override onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(x, y, 200, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.drawTextOnPath(textToDraw, path, textX, textY, paint);
}
```

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawTextOnPath(java.lang.String, android.graphics.Path, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawTextOnPath%28java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Path,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

Comment: Also, For multi-res, use the underlying drawable's height to calculate the radius.

Comment: http://www.networketiquette.net/do_not_use_all_caps.htm  Now, to resume, what does "not working" mean?

Comment: I put this cod in doDraw() but nothing show in screen             canvas.save();
  Path path = new Path();
     path.addCircle(-10, 10, 200, Path.Direction.CW);
     canvas.drawTextOnPath("Hello", path, -10, -10, null);
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     canvas.restore();

Comment: "I put this cod in doDraw()" doDraw, or onDraw?  You also added the circle outside the view.  x = -10 and the text outside the path.  Please edit your question with your onDraw method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18876/discussion-between-rishabh-creatiosoft-and-simon)

Answer (score 4):

You have to create your own object "View" like this

```
public class YourView extends View {
    private static final String YOUR_TEXT = "something cool";
    private Path _arc;

    private Paint _paintText;

    public YourView(Context context) {
      super(context);

      _arc = new Path();
      RectF oval = new RectF(50,100,200,250);;
      _arc.addArc(oval, -180, 200);
      _paintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      _paintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
      _paintText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      _paintText.setTextSize(20f);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.drawTextOnPath(YOUR_TEXT, _arc, 0, 20, _paintText);
      invalidate();
    }
}
```

and then use it as your TextView :) hope this help

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look to the APIDemo source code bundled with the android SDK in your SDK dir.

The example "Graphics/Text Align" (file  TextAlign.java) show how to display a text along a path:
[image: Screen capture of the path]

You can then tweak it to build your screen.

Comment: Thanks for including the image from the API samples.  It saves the time of having to create and run the project.

Comment: https://github.com/appium/android-apidemos/blob/master/src/io/appium/android/apis/graphics/TextAlign.java

Comment: Can you give me a brief description of it?

Comment: Hello sir, how can I do this kind of text in android?

Answer (score 3):

You have implement it using custom views like in your onDraw method:

```
Path path = new Path();
path.addCircle(x, y, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
myCanvas.drawTextOnPath(myText, path, offset, 0, myPaint);
```

Comment: what is x,y and path,offset here?

Answer (score 1):

Try out following code..

```
onDraw(Canvas canvas){
 Path path = new Path();
 path.addArc(oval, startAngle, sweepAngle) 
 path.addArc(oval, 0, 180) 
 }
```

This may work....

Answer (score -11):

You not need to do custom view.
Find correct `TypeFace`,put into your project and set to your `TextView`

Or use microsoft office word art and copy images to your project

[image]

Comment: sorry dude this is not possible with type face,Because type face only gives you style of text not arc shape.

Comment: dear i want to show this style on run time.I could  also use this style with images.But i  never want it.

Comment: This is an android depending question, also the way how to make it in code, not with type face.