# How do to show TextView in curved block?

Tags: android, android-layout

That's how I want to show my text in `TextView`:
[image]

How to set the special bundles for my `TextView`?

Comment: Try creating a background image with the shape and set the image as  background of the textview.

Comment: you should override onDraw's TextView method and draw the text with the given bounds

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13272781/1602230 try some thing like given in the URL