# Circular text around a button

Tags: android

I have a button in ring shape and I want to add a text around a button. Specifically, I want the text as below.
[image]

Comment: Canvas#drawTextOnPath

Comment: @pskink can be more specific please?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple custom view that allows you to draw the text in a circular way.

```
public class GraphicsView extends View {
         private static final String QUOTE = "This is a curved text";
         private Path circle;
         private Paint cPaint;
         private Paint tPaint;

     public GraphicsView(Context context) {
      super(context);

      int color = Color.argb(127, 255, 0, 255);

      circle = new Path();
      circle.addCircle(230, 350, 150, Direction.CW);

      cPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      cPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
      cPaint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
      cPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

      setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart);

      tPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
      tPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      tPaint.setTextSize(50);}

      @Override
         protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         canvas.drawTextOnPath(QUOTE, circle, 485, 20, tPaint);} 
                                            } }
```

**Example :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(new GraphicsView(this));}
}
```

Comment: reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153201/how-to-show-circular-text-using-textview-in-android

Comment: ok this is helpful, but in my activity i have already the setContentView with xml for entire activity, and also I want the textview to be around a button.

Comment: is was just an sample you can place your xml layout in the setContentView

Comment: and how can I call the above class for a specific TextView? I mean that if I have three TextViews which I want to be as above, can I to this inside from xml?

Comment: Then make that view extend a TextView and add the view in your xml