# How to draw background for a text using Canvas in Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas

My requirement is to draw text in a curved path and need to apply some curved background for the curved text as shown in the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghBYV.png)

So far I have done drawing text as a curved path as per the below code:

```
    public GraphicsView(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    super(getApplicationContext());
    circle = new Path();
    circle.addCircle(430, 850, 150, Path.Direction.CW);

    tPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    tPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    tPaint.setTextSize(50);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawTextOnPath(QUOTE, circle, 480, 0, tPaint);
}
```

**Now  my question is how to achieve the background for the curved text as per the attached image.**

Comment: this should help ya. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13272781/8200290

Comment: @DroiDev: I have already done the curved text format. Now i need to display background for the text in the same curved manner shown in the attached image.

Comment: is this for school? why not use an image?