# Android -- Is it possible to warp a TextView?

Tags: android, graphics

I'd like to warp a TextView with an arc shape. I know it's possible to warp images, but is it possible to warp TextViews? Is there a established pattern for doing so?

My other option is to warp the text in Photoshop, save it with a transparent background, and use an ImageView, but a client wants this done in about 10 places and I'd like to avoid the extra resources if I can.

[image: warped text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use customView, override the onDraw(), create a path and use drawTextOnPath.

```
@Override onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    Path mPath = new Path();
    mPath.addCircle(x, y, 200, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.drawTextOnPath(textToDraw, mPath, textX, textY, paint);
}
```

Please have a look [Draw text in circular view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150642/draw-text-in-circular-view)

[How to Show Circular Text using TextView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153201/how-to-show-circular-text-using-textview-in-android)

Comment: This doesn't warp the text itself.

Answer (score 2):

Views in Android are rectangular so you'll have to use Canvas and Paint to achieve your goal.
Take a look at API Demos in the SDK samples. There is one entry called [Graphics/Text Align](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TextAlign.java) which shows text drawn along a curving path.