# How to draw curved text in Android

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm trying to build a text editing app that allows the user to edit text using different fonts, colors, sizes, rotations, etc.  I'm working on a feature that is supposed to curve the text but I've got no clue how to do it.  I found this StackOverflow post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153201/how-to-show-circular-text-using-textview-in-android) and searching through the comments, I found this post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150642/draw-text-in-circular-view) but for what I'm trying to achieve, that is how I want it to end up.  What I want it to do is start as a normal line of text and then based on the value of a `seekbar` I want it to curve, until it reaches the MAX value at which point it's in a circle (as seen in the second link).  If you can help me figure out how to do this I would really appreciate it.  I figure it's going to use `path.addArc` or something like that but I'm not sure.

Thank you

PS
I'll post the images below just in case you don't want to go look at the links

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Answer (score 1):

You can draw your circle text in your custom view, use canvas function drawTextOnPath(String text,Path path, float hOffset, float vOffset,Paint paint), and then construct the path by yourself requirement.