# Curving text in Android

Tags: java, android, textview, curve

I'm creating a text editing app that allows the user to edit text using different fonts, colors, sizes, etc.  Right now I'm working on a feature that is supposed to curve the text.  I already tried asking once [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48106749/how-to-draw-curved-text-in-android/48106875#48106875) but the answer that was posted wasn't really what I was looking for (or maybe it was and I just don't understand exactly what they meant) so I figured I'd ask again with an ACTUAL reference to what I'm trying to accomplish.  [image]  So as you can see, I'm trying to have the text curve based on what the valued of the slider (seekbar in my case) is, but I just don't know how to do it.  I was trying to mimic what is done [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13271645/6810199) specifically the `Along a path` part, but again I'm not sure how to make it work with a `seekbar` as shown in the image.

Thank you

## EDIT

Here's the code that I've been working with.  Like I stated earlier, this my be exactly what I'm looking for and I'm just stupid, but here it is anyways.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class Painting extends Activity
{
    public static int y = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new SampleView(this));
    }

    private static class SampleView extends View
    {
        private Paint mPaint;
        private float mX;
        private float[] mPos;

        private Path mPath;
        private Paint mPathPaint;

        private static final int DY = 30;
        private static final String TEXTONPATH = "Along a path";

        private static void makePath(Path p)
        {
            p.moveTo(10, 0);
            p.cubicTo(00, 00, 00, 00, 900, 00);
        }

        public SampleView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true);

            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setTextSize(90);
            mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);

            mPath = new Path();
            makePath(mPath);

            mPathPaint = new Paint();
            mPathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPathPaint.setColor(0x800000FF);
            mPathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            Paint p = mPaint;
            float x = mX;
            float y = 0;
            float[] pos = mPos;

            p.setColor(0x80FF000);
            canvas.drawLine(x, y, x, y+DY*3, p);
            p.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            canvas.translate(0, DY*10);

            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPathPaint);
            p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
            canvas.drawTextOnPath(TEXTONPATH, mPath, 0, 0, p);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: And where are you at so far? What have you tried up to this point? Can you post some code? Preferably [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrancisBartkowiak please see my edit

Comment: working!.............

Comment: @MarcKaram is your Edit the solution?

Comment: Hello @MarcKaram. Could you please share full your solution? Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to do this with a `TextView`. Instead you will have to write you own class extending `View`.

You will have to override `onDraw` and draw the text onto the `Canvas` there.

To make it work with a `SeekBar` you can use `SeekBar#setOnSeekBarChangeListener`. There in `onProgressChanged` you can tell your View to change its appearance.